# How to echo object name in php?

Tags: php, object

Is there a way to echo the name of a created object?

So if I have created a class Employee, and I have constructor and set and get methods plus a unset method to destruct the attribute values of a object.

So after I for example create a object from class Employee:

```
$emp2 = new Employee();
```

And set the the attributes with the set method and then get the values:

```
$emp2->setEmployeeData("Kalle", "Anka", "002");
echo $emp2->getEmployeeData();
```

This all works as expected. Then I call my destruct method with:

```
echo "Now destroying attributes of " .get_class($emp2) .$emp2->unsetEmployee();
```

This shows the attributes of the class being destructed:

> Now destroying attributes of Employee

But what I would like it to show is the name of the object instead, for example:

> Now destroying attributes of object emp2

So instead of get_class() is there a way to obtain object name instead?

Comment: You can't do that and you really shouldn't http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3881590/can-a-php-object-instance-know-its-name

Comment: You're specifying the object within your string, so surely you can specify which object you're destroying instead of "get_class"?